# How Split String in android containing number

Tags: java, android, string, split

I have dynamic string containing number, how can I separate starting from number for example

```
Golden Apples Perlim 1.000 kg
```

I want to split `Golden Apples Perlim` and `1.000 kg`
and in `Lemon 1.000 kg` i want to split
`Lemon` and `1.000 kg` separably

how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex split:

```java
String input = "Golden Apples Perlim 1.000 kg";
String[] parts = input.split("\\s+(?=\\d(?:\\.\\d+)?)");
for (String part : parts) {
    System.out.println(part);
}
```

This prints:

```
Golden Apples Perlim
1.000 kg
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Pattern and Matcher with this regex [`(\D+?)(\d.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/t5BE98/1):

```
String[] strs = {"Golden Apples Perlim 1.000 kg", "Lemon 1.000 kg"};
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\D+?)(\\d.*)");
Matcher matcher;
for (String str : strs) {
  matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
  if (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
  }
}
```

**Outputs**

```
Golden Apples Perlim 
1.000 kg
Lemon 
1.000 kg
```